# pyspark to convert single col into multiple cols

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a dataframe as below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID|DATASET                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|4A|[{"col.1":"12ABC","col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"}]   |
|8B|[{"col.1":"12ABC","col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"}]   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+----------------------------------+
|ID|col_1 | col_2 | col_3| col_4   |
+----------------------------------+
|4A|"12ABC"|"141"||"ABCD"          |
|8B|"12ABC"|"141"||"ABCD"          |
+--------------------------------- +
```

- *i tried to use regex_extract* :

df.withColumn("col_1", regexp_extract("DATASET", "(?<=col.1:)\w+(?=(,|}|]))", 0)).withColumn("col_2", regexp_extract("DATASET", "(?<=col.2:)\w+(?=(,|}|]))", 0))

but getting null values in the result

```
+----------------------------------+
|ID|col_1 | col_2 | col_3| col_4   |
+----------------------------------+
|4A||||                            |
|8B||||                            |
+--------------------------------- +
```

Any input on this

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

Thanks for the response, that works fine, my input getting changed a little bit, i want to group based on col1 and place values in separate rows

**Updated Dataset:**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID|DATASET                                                                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4A|[{"col.1":"12ABC","col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"},{"col.1":"13ABC","col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"}]   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID|col_1 | col_2 | col                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|4A|"12ABC"|"{"col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"}"           |
|4A|"13ABC"|"{"col.2":"141","col.3":"","col.4":"ABCD"}"           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using structfield

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('`col.1`', StringType(), True),
    StructField('`col.2`', StringType(), True),
    StructField('`col.3`', StringType(), True),
    StructField('`col.4`', StringType(), True),
]
)

df.withColumn("DATASET", from_json("DATASET", schema))\
.select(col('ID'), col('data.*'))\
.show()
```